# Can I apply for the right to remain in the UK after my 2 year ban is up?

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, removal

Seven months ago, I was removed from the UK, as my right to remain application was refused, due to some mistakes made by my lawyer.

I was 8 years old when my family applied for the right to remain but overstayed, and now at 18, I and my family were refused. We left voluntarily within 6 months of the refusal, but still have a 2 year ban just for overstaying.

Would I be able to apply for the right to remain after my ban is up or will it be difficult? During that time, I'll be going to uni in Canada.

Comment: @pnuts That's an extremely cryptic comment, which is unlikely to be of any use to the asker.